# Get Business Information using twitter api

Tags: api, twitter

I am trying to get the business information of a registered organization using its Website URL.
I searched in many ways. Now, I had downloaded the Twitter API PHP SDK from github. 
From the below link

```
https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php
```

In my index.php page, I have changed my code to

```
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json';
$getfield = '?q=Twitter%20API';
$requestMethod = 'GET';
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
echo $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
             ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
             ->performRequest();
```

But, it gives me an empty result in the browser.
Please help me in getting some result out of it.
Thanks in advance!

---

I still didn't find any answer for my question. Now, I had downloaded the Twitter API PHP SDK from github. 
From the below link

```
https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php
```

In my index.php page, I have changed my code to

```
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json';
$getfield = '?q=Twitter%20API';
$requestMethod = 'GET';
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
echo $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
             ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
             ->performRequest();
```

But, it gives me an empty result in the browser.
Please help me in getting some result out of it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't down vote, if u have any idea abt this, please give me suggestions

Comment: `However, it is not working` gives people absolutely nothing to work with.  *How* is it not working?  Are you getting an error?  No data?  Nothing at all?  Also, telling people `Don't downvote` when the question is unclear is only going to result in *more* downvotes.

Comment: Check the error what i am getting with the above url

Comment: Also, *thanks for serially down voting me* ... at least all 9 downvotes got reversed.  I didn't even down vote your question, I'm not sure why you felt the need to do that.

Comment: sorry for that, i am in a kind of frustation @LittleBobbyTables

Answer (score 2):

The error message you are receiving tells you the answer:

**The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1.**

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview

Use the current API not the old one.